# CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=13.0.4000.0 uses higher version of CrystalDecisions.CrystalReport.ENGINE, version=13.0.2000.0

Tags: c#, visual-studio, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010

Assembly 'CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=13.0.4000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' uses 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.4000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304'    c:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win32_x86\dotnet\CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.dll

Answer (score 0):

you have to install crystal reports for visual studio runtime sp20 or lower